# Error adding a theme

Tags: android, android-theme

I am getting an error when I try adding a theme in the manifest, telling the resource is not found. How do I fix this problem?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="Texttheme" >
        <item name="android:textColor">#ff0000</item>
    </style>
</resources>

<activity android:name=".Funfriends" 
          android:theme="@string/Texttheme"
          android:label="@string/app_name">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="nik.trivia.FUNFRIENDS" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: The xml file is put in values directory..This the only change I made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `@string/Texttheme` to `@style/Texttheme`, this should be the case.

Answer (score 0):

Use a style file for this. Refer to the documentation in *[Applying Styles and Themes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html)*.